# Find OGP tag by PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom

Sorry It might too simple question. 
However I can't find solution.

I try to find the OGP tag like this

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MyTitle" />
<meta property="og:type" content="MyProduct" />
```

I red [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)  and try very simple php script.

```
$html = str_get_html($source);
$meta = $html->find("meta[property=og:title]");
var_dump($meta->content);
```

It shows nothing.
How can I get content??

Comment: `->find` always returns an array of elements. Use `var_dump($meta[0]->content);`

Comment: Please don't use SimpleHTMLDom, there are vastly better options available ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I'd try `$html->find('meta[property="og:title"]', 0)` to return the first object found instead of a collection. Also note the quotes around the attribute value

Comment: Thank you ,, your answer is quite correct. I made very beginner mistake.